# Make NSDictionary throw exception when object not found

Tags: objective-c, exception, nsdictionary

I would like to make a NSDictionary throw an exception instead of returning a nil when a key is not found.

I've done some research and, ok, I get it, it is a bad idea to subclass any of the collection classes. Then, what would be the best approach to achieve this?

Notice I would like to preserve the subscript syntax, and the creation via literals, or at least get the most out of it.

The category approach is easy but doesn't let me use the subscript syntax:

```
id value = dict[@"non-existing-key"]; // throws exception
```

And the wrapper approach doesn't let me use the literal creation:

```
MyDictWrapper *dict = @{ @"key" : @"value" }; // this returns a standard NSDictionary
```

Is there a way to make a dictionary throw and exception when the item is not found and preserve this very useful and handy syntax?

Comment: The thing is ... why would you want to do this? I strongly advise against it.

Comment: I have a library that is using a promises framework to develop a series of tasks. Whenever an exception is thrown it jumps to the error callback promise where it handles it. This library is performing JSON connections and receiving its responses in a form of a dictionary, if for whatever reason the server changes the response format, I do not want the library to read a nil from the response dictionary and propagate it throughout the code, I want it to immediately treat it as an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
void swizzleInstance(SEL originalSl, SEL swizzledSl, Class originalCl, Class swizzledCl) {
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(originalCl, originalSl);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(swizzledCl, swizzledSl);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
}
@implementation NSDictionary(ExceptionForKey)

- (id)objectForKey_m:(NSString *)aKey
{
    id object = [self objectForKey_m:aKey];
    if (!object) {
        [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Object not found"
                                reason:[@"Object not found for key: " stringByAppendingString:aKey]
                              userInfo:nil];
    }
    return object;
}

+ (void)load {
    swizzleInstance(@selector(objectForKey:),
                    @selector(objectForKey_m:),
                    [NSDictionary class],
                    [NSDictionary class]);
}

@end
```

Comment: this will not work, there is some magic NSDictionary objectForKey: is never called,lldb command "breakpoint set --selector "-[NSDictionary objectForKey:]"" doesn't take any effect

Comment: True, also it would be "id object = [self objectForKey: aKey];" and you would need to swizzle the "objectForKeyedSubscript:" method. Done it. It works, but the app crashes because with this you are exchanging the implementation of all the NSDictionary instances and it looks it's being called somewhere else in the Cocoa Touch framework where a nil is expected...

Comment: aaah, what I can advise to check frame, and caller method ([NSThread callStackSymbols];) and check if it's called from your side.